# How to get a pandas index value of a string

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

**Background:**
Searching through a spreadsheet with many thousands of rows.  Just need to get the index value--as an int--to then get the value of other columns in that same row.  I'm just trying to transfer specific values from one spreadsheet (.csv) to an excel sheet.

So, basically the goal is; if column A contains XYZ, give me the value of column B,D,etc...  The breakdown of that though (from my understanding); is to get the index of XYZ, then lookup the value of column B at the index number.  Once I have the raw values of the columns, I can do whatever with it.

It's that first step that I'm stuck at, at the moment.

Version: Python 3.6.7

---

Here's the specific code that I'm having problems with:

570-177736 is the value I'm searching for in a column:

> ```
> >>> parcel_csv.index[570-177736]
> 203740
> ```

203740 is the index number, as I understand it.

However, when I use a variable in the index brackets (for loop) I get the same error as what's listed below.  I added the single-quotes because I believe that's how it appears as the value in the variable (it's the same error):

> ```
> >>> parcel_csv.index['570-177736']
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/home/localuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py", line 522, in __getitem__
>     raise IndexError("only integers, slices (`:`), "
> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
> ```

Let me know if you need more info.  Thank you!

Comment: You are a little confused about indexing, I would suggest rereading https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html. `parcel_csv.index[570-177736]` is equivalent to `parcel_csv.index[-177166]` which just means index the `177166` value from the end. To select the row(s) with your search for term you probably mean something along the lines of `parcel_csv[parcel_csv[<column>] == '570-177736']` (boolean indexing) which will give you all the columns for the rows that have `'570-177736'` in the the column `<column>`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: `parcel_csv[parcel_csv.A == '570-177736']` Will return you the row where column `A` is `570-177736`. To access corresponding column `B` value, use `parcel_csv[parcel_csv.A == '570-177736'].B`